# Custom HTTP Header in Django

Tags: django

I use a custom http header for URL signature just called "sign", how to get such custom HTTP header value in Django?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Go ahead and use:

```
request.META.get('HTTP_{your uppercased header name}')
```

Note in Django you write the header name in capitals with underscores instead of dashes, but in the request on the client you must write it using dashes instead of underscores (production web servers will strip out custom headers with underscores in them for security reasons).

So, a custom header `My-Custom-Header` is accessed `request.META['HTTP_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER']`

Answer (score 17):

Finally I found just get it through

```
request.META.get('HTTP_YOUR_CUSTOM_HEADER') # hyphens are converted to underscores and the header is prefixed with HTTP_.
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful pointer. Besides uppercasing the header name, I had to replace dashes with underscores. So, header name "My-custom-header" is request.META['HTTP_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER']

Comment: This code gives the following error `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`. Calling `request.META.get('HTTP_{your uppercased header name}')` is the correct way.

Answer (score 16):

You can add your own custom headers to a response like so:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#setting-headers

```
>>> response = HttpResponse()
>>> response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
>>> del response['Cache-Control']
```

Or use a decorator to add them to a view:
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/275/

Answer (score 8):

I was trying to access the header with the above answers, using this code:

```py
request.META.get('HTTP_{your uppercased header name}')
```

But It didn't work for me, and then I realized that the custom header should not contain `underscore` so I changed the `underscore` with `dash` and boom, everything started working. Hope this will help people like me. :-)

Comment: It's not my case but I believe your comment is useful.

Answer (score 7):

As of Django 2.2 you can use the `HttpRequest.headers` dictionary which provides case-insensitive dictionary of request headers, like such:

```
my_header = request.headers.get('x-my-custom-header')
```

See [django.http.HttpRequest.headers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.headers)

Comment: How would you set the header this way?

Answer (score 3):

From the Django documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

> With the exception of CONTENT_LENGTH and CONTENT_TYPE, as given above,
>   any HTTP  headers in the request are converted to META keys by
>   converting all characters  to uppercase, replacing any hyphens with
>   underscores and adding an HTTP_ prefix  to the name. So, for example,
>   a header called X-Bender would be mapped to the  META key
>   HTTP_X_BENDER.