# how to crawl a page by using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have two pages (A and B), which are written by using django + jquery. and their urls are:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/temp1/ (pageA)
http://127.0.0.1:8082/temp2/ (pageB)
```

I want to crawl page B in page A's js script by using ajax(), and the js script is:

```
 $("#tmp_button1").click(function(tmp_event) {
    $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8082/temp2/",
            async: false,
            headers: {
                   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
            },
            error: function(request, error) {
                    alert(error);
            },
            success: function(response) {
                    alert(response);
            }
    });
});
```

unfortunately, I could not crawl the page B. is this a cross-domain action? if I want to crawl page B by using jquery, what should I do?

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The ports differ so your server (request target server) need to allow cross-domain requests.
Just send this header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

E.g. for PHP ( http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html ):

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Or use .htaccess ( http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html ):

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

More infos and how to: http://enable-cors.org/server.html

You can also use [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).
Sample here (may help): [JSONP web service with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574850/jsonp-web-service-with-python)

Comment: thank you very much, I add "<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">" in page B, and I would get a "parsererror" if I crawl page B, what should I do? ps. the page B is just a simple html, no js, no css.

Comment: You need to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to HTTP header not to HTML header.

Comment: I add it in ajax as described above, but it still does not work.

Comment: You need to add it to your server, not to the javascript code. What server are you using?

Comment: there are only two pages(A and B), which are written by django + jquery. the server is django?

Comment: The application running on 127.0.0.1:8082 that replies to your browser with the HTML code.

Comment: Yes, django is your server. This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377050/custom-http-header-in-django

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that because of the same source policy.
Page **A** and page **B** are from different domains since the port number differs.

Check Jsonp: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP which maybe the solution.